# Modular-inverse algorithm

Tags: algorithm, scheme

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [multiplicative inverse of modulo m in scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096491/multiplicative-inverse-of-modulo-m-in-scheme)

I have written a code for finding to solve x and y as a pair.
I need to write a modular-inverse code that finds the multiplicative inverse of e modulo n, using ax + by = 1.

> Blockquote

```
(define (ax+by=1 a b)
        (if (= b 0)
            (cons 1 0)
            (let* ((q (quotient a b))
                   (r (remainder a b))
                   (e (ax+by=1 b r))
                   (s (car e))
                   (t (cdr e)))
           (cons t (- s (* q t))))))
```

Edit : Problem Solved with the function below.

> Blockquote

```
 (define inverse-mod (lambda (a m) 
                  (if (not (= 1 (gcd a m)))
                      (display "**Error** No inverse exists.")
                      (if (> 0(car (ax+by=1 a m)))
                          (+ (car (ax+by=1 a m)) m)
                          (car (ax+by=1 a m))))))
```

Comment: [In here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096491/multiplicative-inverse-of-modulo-m-in-scheme) they did the same thing but i'm new to scheme. i did not get how they did it in the confirmed answer.

Comment: after examining more, 'egcd' in the link I have given is an equivalent process to my 'ax+by=1' , but i still did not get the logic of this statement. ` (let-values (((g x y) (egcd a m)))` .

Comment: @Dr.Oz `let-values` binds to multiple variables the result of evaluating a procedure that returns multiple values, `egcd` in this case

Answer (score 0):

Consider the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

This uses the extended euclidean algorithm to find the modular inverse:

```
(define (inverse x m)
  (let loop ((x x) (b m) (a 0) (u 1))
    (if (zero? x)
        (if (= b 1) (modulo a m)
          (error 'inverse "must be coprime"))
        (let* ((q (quotient b x)))
          (loop (modulo b x) x u (- a (* u q)))))))
```